# SQL Query result and SSRS result dont match

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have created a SQL that can pass in multiple parameters and more than one condition.

Example

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM movement 
 WHERE Arrivalid  IN (@ArrivalID) OR DepartureID IN (@DepartureID)
```

With this script, `SELECT * FROM movement WHERE Arrivalid IN ('A_1234') OR DepartureID IN ('')`, i am able to pull out record from SSMS.
However, when I run it in SSRS, SSRS return me empty record.
Btw, the query is created as Dataset in SSRS.

Is it a must to pass in 2 parameters? But I have already set "allow blank value ("")".
[Report Parameter Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3mit.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3mit.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AJwO.png

There is no filter created on this simple table format.
[SSRS Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3mit.png)
Does anyone have any idea what has gone wrong with my SSRS setup?

To add on:

In Dataset properties, i have added "Spilt" for multiple parameter.
[Expression for parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/addyu.png)

Setting for Default Values 
[Parameters - Default Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYj9i.png)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to be able to enter either arrival or departure IDs then you should be able to just do this...

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM movement 
 WHERE (Arrivalid IN (@ArrivalID) OR @ArrivalID IS NULL)
       OR (DepartureID IN (@DepartureID) OR @DepartureID IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting default value for that parameter:[image]

Comment: i do have some list of default value for Arrival and Departure.  I do not have issue, if i have both parameters entered. However, it there is only 1, the record will be empty in SSRS.

Comment: Can you try pass NULL value, and then in dataset make line: SET @Parameter = isnull(@Parameter,'') before select? That will set all null inputs to blank text.

Comment: your issue should be solved via @AlanSchofield's suggestion above. Its a query thing and not ssrs. Try running your stored proc or query by declaring those exact same params and running the query. Rem ssrs just render's what sql server throws at it.